# Upgrade from Laravel 4.1 to directly Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I have an app which was developed 3-4 years back in Laravel 4.1 and as per the current need I've been asked to port the web application written in Laravel 4.1 to current stable and recent version of Laravel 5.3 ***directly*** (without stepwise upgrade to 4.2/5.0/5.1 or 5.2). Is it better to port which may take a lot of time due to architectural change difference or rewrite everything from scratch in the latest Laravel 5.3 version?

Thank you,

Rohit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the size of your application, it may be easier to just create a new 5.3 application and copy over your files and making the necessary modifications as you go.

There would be no way to just directly upgrade from 4.1 to 5.3 - you'd have to do all the steps in between in some manner.

Comment: Ahan, well the application is quite big and complex. It's sort of employee management system written by some programmer in the firm 3-4 years back, no tech documentation provided as well by the previous programmer that leaves me guessing the flow by reading the code flow + trial and error method. What's your say?

Comment: I would have to agree with @Darren Taylor. There are a large number of concept, structure and framework changes. You could try and move all of the Application files into their new locations under a fresh 5.3 install bit by bit. Try and rebuild the application from the ground up. Should allow you to fix as you go

Comment: @rohitpaniker my gut feeling would still be to create a new 5.3 app and build it up, piece by piece. So I would maybe start by getting all the Models ported over, then the routes, any composer packages, then the controllers, config files, etc. etc. and testing it as you go.

It's not going to be quick or easy - but it might be easier than upgrading, step by step.

Comment: @scottevans93 Yup I too agree with him, I've decided to build the whole application from scratch now as I tried porting but each and every file is going through loads of changes to comply with the new 5.3 architectural changes so might as well build the app again from scratch as best option than guess the flow and edit files. 

Thank you scottevans93 and Darren Taylor :)